# Butterknife Nullpointer exception in android 4.2

Tags: android, android-studio, butterknife

Using Butterknife in my current project; it works fine on Kitkat and lollipop but throws a nullpointer exception on jellybean (4.2).

**Exception is thrown at this line (btnLogin is NULL)**

btnLogin.setTypeface(FontsHelper.robotoRegular(this));

Activity Code

```
public class Login extends Activity {
    @Bind(R.id.btnLogin)
    FButton btnLogin;

    @Bind(R.id.btnRegister)
    FButton btnRegister;

    @Bind(R.id.edtEmail)
    EditText edtEmail;

    @Bind(R.id.edtPassword)
    EditText edtPassword;

    @Bind(R.id.rlProgress)
    RelativeLayout rlProgress;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);
        System.out.println("Binding password" + edtPassword); //prints null
        System.out.println("Binding "+btnLogin); //prints null
        btnLogin.setTypeface(FontsHelper.robotoRegular(this));
    }
}
```

The layout....

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center">
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/imageView1" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp" android:src="@drawable/lm_logo_with_text"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"  android:paddingLeft="@dimen/pad_40dp"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/pad_40dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"/>
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/llContent" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp" android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:orientation="vertical"  android:paddingLeft="@dimen/pad_40dp" android:paddingRight="@dimen/pad_40dp">
        <EditText android:id="@+id/edtEmail" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:hint="Email"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_email" android:inputType="textEmailAddress" style="@style/txt_white">
            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>
        <View android:background="@color/gray"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="@dimen/divider" android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/pad_16dp" />
        <EditText android:id="@+id/edtPassword" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:hint="Password"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_pwd" android:inputType="textPassword" style="@style/txt_white" />
        <View  android:background="@color/gray"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="@dimen/divider" />
        <View android:background="@color/gray"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="@dimen/divider" android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/pad_16dp"
            android:visibility="gone"/>
        <EditText android:id="@+id/edtEmailUnused" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:hint="Email address"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_pwd" android:inputType="textEmailAddress" style="@style/txt_white"
            android:visibility="gone"/>
        <info.hoang8f.widget.FButton
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:id="@+id/btnLogin"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            fbutton:buttonColor="@color/picton_blue"
            fbutton:shadowColor="@color/san_marino"
            fbutton:shadowEnabled="true"
            fbutton:shadowHeight="2dp"
            fbutton:cornerRadius="2dp"
            android:text="Login"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/pad_10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/pad_40dp"
            android:padding="@dimen/pad_15dp"
            />
        <info.hoang8f.widget.FButton
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:id="@+id/btnRegister"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            fbutton:buttonColor="@color/niagara"
            fbutton:shadowColor="@color/san_marino"
            fbutton:shadowEnabled="true"
            fbutton:shadowHeight="2dp"
            fbutton:cornerRadius="2dp"
            android:text="Register"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/pad_40dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/pad_5dp"
            android:padding="@dimen/pad_15dp"
            android:onClick="gotoHome"
            />


        <Button android:id="@+id/btnFb" android:background="@drawable/btn_fb"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" style="@style/btn" android:visibility="gone"/>


    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/rlProgress"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/white_45_percent"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
    android:visibility="gone"
    xmlns:wheel="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <com.pnikosis.materialishprogress.ProgressWheel
        android:id="@+id/progress_wheel"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        wheel:matProg_barColor="#555588FF"
        wheel:matProg_progressIndeterminate="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Stack trace

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{lifemedico.array.com.lifemedico/lifemedico.array.com.lifemedico.ui.login.Login}: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at lifemedico.array.com.lifemedico.ui.login.Login.onCreate(Login.java:52)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
    ... 11 more
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at lifemedico.array.com.lifemedico.ui.login.Login.onCreate(Login.java:52)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

There are no issues what so ever on lollipop and kitkat, but the debug statements both print null in jelly bean. Can't think of any reasons this is failing, any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks

Edit:

*Adding debug option to butterknife gave me this
Not found. Trying superclass android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityd
MISS: Reached framework class. Abandoning search.
Some search online pointed to proguard, but i am not using proguard and this is still a debug version.*

Comment: Hey Boss, am using android studio.

Comment: What line is the exception being thrown?

Comment: Updated the question; exception is thrown  at btnLogin.setTypeface(FontsHelper.robotoRegular(this)) . btnLogin is null

Comment: could you post the stack trace that you get in your logcat? and why not use Log.d or Log.e Log.i etc for logging instead of system.out,println

Comment: u shd print the stacktrace..i know not valid but may be jelly bean still uses injectview..u can try..

Comment: I know this might seem like a silly suggestion, but have you checked all of your dependencies? Are you referencing the proper XML? Without the stack trace it's hard to say for sure..

Comment: I guess i tried both, thought an upgrade to butterknife would solve the problem. But it did not. Added the stack trace.

Comment: @Zack; Just added the stack trace. i Have'nt had any issues running on kitkat or lollipop. The xml seems to fine and works as expected. Am more inclined towards something that i am missing, may be a compiler setting?

Comment: Thanks for that @Veeru. Could this be something to do with FontsHelper? Could you comment out that line and tell us if something changes? I'm not sure what that class does exactly.

Comment: @zack; i have done preliminary debugging - btnLogin is null, so calling any function on it would result in NullPointerException. In fact all variables return nulls in JB but return respective views in KitKat and Lollipop.

Comment: Added an answer. Let me know if that helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Guess i was looking down the wrong hole; there is no programming/syntax/logic error. As i have mentioned i looked into proguard and realized my gradle has ***multiDexEnabled***; and for some reason Butterknife functions are stripped out. All i had to do is set my App to extend MultiDexApplication and it worked like a charm; took me a day to figure it out.

```
public class App  extends MultiDexApplication {
```

I found a lead in this post https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife/issues/311

Comment: am glad it helped someone else too :)

Comment: working for me...thank you @Veeru....but still I am not understading why its happened...

Answer (score 1):

this issue can be resolved by updating your gradle file as mention by Butterknife on their gitgub

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    mavenCentral()
   }
  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'
  }
}

apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'

dependencies {
  compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.0.1'
  apt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.0.1'
}
```

For exact reference you can refer link https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife

Answer (score 0):

Please make your fields public i.e.:

```
@Bind(R.id.btnLogin)
public FButton btnLogin;

@Bind(R.id.btnRegister)
public FButton btnRegister;

@Bind(R.id.edtEmail)
public EditText edtEmail;

@Bind(R.id.edtPassword)
public EditText edtPassword;

@Bind(R.id.rlProgress)
public RelativeLayout rlProgress;
```

Butterknife cannot bind private variables, so make it public

Comment: Doubt that's the case kabindra, it works on kitkat and lollipop. For the sake of your suggestion, i tried it and its still the same